# Repeat Control using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'll probably lose reputation for asking this; but I've been trying infinite variations of code, and failing every time. So I'm reaching out.

I'm working on an aspx. It's all built, they just want some additional functionality.

We're using [ScriptSharp](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp) to trans-compile to JavaScript.

Basically, we've got an HTML table. Each row in the table represents an invoice. One column in the table represents the amount due (call it `amountDue`) on the invoice. Another column on the table contains a textbox wherein the user may enter the amount to apply to the invoice (call it `amountToPay`). If the amounts differ, another column populates with a textbox, pre-populated with the difference between the amount due and the amount entered (call it `difference`). Following this column is another column with a drop-down list of reasons to explain the discrepancy (call it `reason`). The user may change the difference in the `difference` textbox. If that happens, a new additional `difference` textbox and a new additional `reason` drop-down list need to appear on the same row of the table, each under its appropriate column.

My first attempts duplicated controls geometrically, for example, going from two `difference` textboxes to eight. I figured that out.

Now every combination of jQuery functions I try either duplicates all the controls, or none of the controls. So, on `difference` change, either no new `difference` textbox is added, or the number of `difference` textboxes that exist is added. So if two exist, four result. If four exist, eight result.

Okay, here's some code.

Here are the two columns for `difference` and `reason`.

```
<td class="currency">
    <div>
        <input class="difference_textbox" type="text" value="0.00" style="display: none;" />
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div>
        <select style="display: none;" class="adj_reason_select">
            <option></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</td>
```

I'll skip the ScriptSharp and just list the trans-compiled JavaScript (debug version):

```
// Let this function represent the function called on `difference` change.
ReceivePayment._addAdjustment = function ReceivePayment$_addAdjustment(e) {
    var self = $(e.target);
    var customerInvoice = self.parents('.customer_invoice');
    var amountPaidBox = customerInvoice.find('.amount_to_pay_input');
    // ...
    var amountPaidTD = amountPaidBox.closest('td');
    var diffTextBoxTD = ReceivePayment._duplicateInputControl(amountPaidTD);
    var adjReasonSelectTD = ReceivePayment._duplicateInputControl(diffTextBoxTD);
    // ...
}

ReceivePayment._duplicateInputControl = function ReceivePayment$_duplicateInputControl(td) {
    // This is very verbose so that I can stop at any point and
    // examine what I've got.
    var o = td.next();       // Grab the next td.
    var divs = o.children(); // Grab the div(s) contained within the td.
    var div = divs.last();   // Grab the last div within the td.
    // And here's where all my gyrations occur, infinite permutations
    // of jQuery calls, not one permutation of which has succeeded in
    // adding the contents of the final div to the list of divs.
    var d = div[0];
    var html = d.outerHTML;
    var s = html.toString();
    div.add(s);
    return o;
}
```

My attempts include calling `after`, `insertAfter`, `html`, `clone`, `cloneNode`, `appendChild`, and on, and on, on different objects, including `divs`, `div`, `o`, etc.

Part of my problem is that I've not worked with jQuery much. I know just enough to be dangerous. But surely this is possible. Given a `td`, find the following `td`. Within that `td` will be a list of one or more `div`s. Get the last of those `div`s, copy it, and append that copy to the list of `div`s. Done.

What, oh what, am I missing? Flame on.

Comment: try something like : `divs.append(div.clone())` right after you define `divs` and `div`

Comment: Thanks, @charlietfl. Unfortunately, that duplicates all the `div`s. So it adds one the first time, two the second time, four the third time, etc. I also tried `div.append(div.clone())`. Same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appear to have stumbled upon the solution after a shameful amount of time spent spinning my wheels. I gave up. Then, of course, it hit me:

```
ReceivePayment._duplicateInputControl = function ReceivePayment$_duplicateInputControl(td) {
    // This is very verbose so that I can stop at any point and
    // examine what I've got.
    var o = td.next();       // Grab the next td.
    var divs = o.children(); // Grab the div(s) contained within the td.
    var div = divs.last();   // Grab the last div within the td.
    o.append(div.clone());
    return o;
}
```